# Power BI - Count unique occurrence of an entire row ("Count(*)" equivalent in SQL)

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I am trying to add a column in my table in Power BI with the total counts for each unique row. I hope to have a formula that will retrieve the total counts for each row that meet the criteria of each of the column values for each of these rows within my table.

Basically I want to do the SQL equivalent of a Count(*) within a SELECT statement if that makes sense.

I have:

```
field_1 field_2 field_3  
client 1    US  Y    
client 1    US  Y    
client 2    CA  Y    
client 3    FR  N    
client 3    FR  N    
client 3    FR  N
```

And I want:

```
field_1 field_2 field_3 Counts 
client 1    US  Y       2
client 1    US  Y       2
client 2    CA  Y       1
client 3    FR  N       3
client 3    FR  N       3
client 3    FR  N       3
```

Comment: Can you please improve your question by providing sample data and expected output?

Comment: sorry about that, just added

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this in DAX

```
_uniqueRowCount = 
MAXX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        tbl2,
        "uniqueRowCount",
            COUNTX (
                FILTER (
                    tbl2,
                    tbl2[field_1] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_1] )
                        && tbl2[field_2] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_2] )
                        && tbl2[field_3] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_3] )
                ),
                tbl2[field_1]
            )
    ),
    [uniqueRowCount]
)
```

[image: Solution]

and if you are looking for a column

```
Column = 
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        tbl2,
        tbl2[field_1] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_1] )
            && tbl2[field_2] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_2] )
            && tbl2[field_3] = EARLIER ( tbl2[field_3] )
    ),
    tbl2[field_1]
)
```

[image: S2]

Comment: what if I have n number of fields and I want to do a count on all

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to reference an arbitrarily number of columns within DAX. Each column must be referenced explicitly. Perhaps first add a column which concatenates the required columns within Power Query, after which the required DAX formula should be straightforward.

Comment: If you want to achieve the same result in SQL; the equivalent SQL is `select field_1,field_2, field_3 ,COUNT(field_1) over (partition by field_1,field_2,field_3) as count from @t1`. Doing a `COUNT(*)` will not help you get the desired result in SQL. So in SQL you need to explicitly mention the the fields inside `over (partition by -----)`. For n number of field SQL can't return the count unless you mention them explicitly. DAX is no different.

Comment: try out this SQL `declare @t1 as table (field_1 varchar(max), field_2 varchar(max),field_3 varchar(max),ID int) insert into @t1 select * from (values('client 1','US','Y',1),('client 1','US','Y',2),('client 1','US','N',3), ('client 2','CA','Y',4),('client 3','FR','N',5),('client 3','FR','N',6),('client 3','FR','N',7)) t (a,b,c,d)` `select field_1,field_2, field_3,ID ,COUNT(field_1) over (partition by field_1,field_2,field_3) as count from @t1 order by ID`